# parse XML file for images

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have an XML file which contain images, The images are of the form [[ID]] where ID is the unique identifier for an image stored in the database. I want to parse this XML file for [[ ]] tags and replace the tags with the images which will be fetched from the database. Upto this point, this is what I have done

```
 string xmlUrl = Server.MapPath("/Model Report.xsl");
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(xmlUrl);
```

now want to parse doc for [[ ]] tags. The image in the XML file looks like this(this is only a part of XML file.)

```
 <table-graphics.as-jpeg datatype="string" display-name="As JPEG">[[ID]]</table-graphics.as-jpeg>
```

Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean "replace the tags with the images"? Are you planning to store image data in the XML file?

Comment: @IainBallard : yes my XML file contains images which need to be retrived from the database

Comment: So, how do you intend to encode the image in the XML? Are you asking how to look up in a database, or how to encode bytes to base64, or how to find text in XML?

Comment: If you see my question , the image comes from database and I want [[ID]] brackets in the XML file to replace the image coming from database, here ID id the unique identifier for the image. My question does not intend to ask how to look up in a database or encode bytes to base64 or how to find text in XML

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XPath support in C# to help with the parsing.

*[...edit...]*
You'll want to look for the **table-graphics.as-jpeg** elements, then grab their text content. (Don't have the exact syntax in my head -- I always have to look it up myself.)

Comment: The tutorials on the internet give a fair idea of retrieving child elements, attributes, value of element, etc. but what I want is scan the entire XML file for [[ ]] tags, if you could provide help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear to me what you are asking. Sounds like you are trying to treat the XML document like a plain text document; in which case:

```
string xmlUrl = Server.MapPath("/Model Report.xsl");
string raw = new WebClient().DownloadString(xmlUrl);

var output = new List<string>();

int left = 0;
int right = 0;
while ((left = raw.IndexOf("[[", right)) >= 0) {
    int right = raw.IndexOf("]]", left);
    if (right > left) output.Add(raw.Substring(left+2, right-left-2));
}
```

should give all the **[[**`something`**]]** patterns in the document.

If you know more about the document, like all the IDs will be in `table-graphics.as-jpeg` tags, you should use the XPath support as Mark said:

```
string xmlUrl = Server.MapPath("/Model Report.xsl");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlUrl);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//table-graphics.as-jpeg"))
{
    node.InnerText . . .
}
```